# etcd dns-discovery within cloud-init

Tags: coreos

How can I bootstrap a CoreOS cluster with etcd peer dns discovery via cloud-init?

I've only found examples using the discovery token service, but nothing for dns discovery. The documentation about this is really sparse, but it gets mentioned sometimes.

**UPDATE:**

I search for a possibility to startup a cluster and to use DNS discovery for etcd like described here: https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/a4018f25c91fff8f4f15cd2cee9f026650c7e688/Documentation/clustering.md#dns-discovery.

In theory I want to replace "discovery:" with something like "discover-srv:", but I don't know if this is possible by now with cloud-init. I've tried and failed so far.

Comment: are you talking about etcd peer discovery, or container discovery using skydns/registrator?

Comment: about the peer discovery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code I think the setting you need is named:

```
discovery_srv
```

In the etcd2 section.  I imagine it should take the same settings as described in the link you provided.  It gets translated to the environment variable ETCD_DISCOVERY_SRV

Another settings of note are:

```
proxy
proxy_srv
```

e.g.  At a guess, something like the following may work.  I also have a feeling that if you use dashes they get changed to underscores so discovery-srv and discovery_srv may be equivalent.  Don't quote me on that!

```
coreos:
  etcd2:
    name: <hostname matching srv record>
    discovery_srv: example.com
    initial_cluster_state: new
    # multi-region and multi-cloud deployments need to use $public_ipv4
    advertise_client_urls: http://$public_ipv4:2379
    initial_advertise_peer_urls: http://$private_ipv4:2380
    # listen on both the official ports and the legacy ports
    # legacy ports can be omitted if your application doesn't depend on them
    listen_client_urls: http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
    listen_peer_urls: http://$private_ipv4:2380,http://$private_ipv4:7001
```

--- edit ---

I can confirm the following works for nodes that require proxying.

```
# cloud-config

coreos:
  etcd2:
    discovery-srv: example.com
    proxy: on
  units:
    name: etcd2.service
    command: start
```

Comment: Finally had the time to check it out: It works, thanks!

Adding a proxy-member worked. But what not worked for me, was adding a new member to the cluster. Does a new cluster member has to be in the SRV entries at boot time?

Comment: Found out how to add new member afterwards: https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/runtime-configuration.md#add-a-new-member  - The IP of the new node has to be added as member in etcd and in the SRV entries  BEFORE the node gets started up.